# Parse signed number from hex using BigInt

Tags: scala

I'm trying to parse a signed number using a `BigInt`. Here have been my attempts

```
scala> -1.toHexString
res7: String = ffffffff

scala> val bigInt = BigInt(res7,16)
bigInt: scala.math.BigInt = 4294967295
```

Is there any way to easily parse a signed number from a hex using `BigInt`?

Answer (score 1):

If your hex string began life as an Integer or a Long—before converting it to a BigInt—parse it as an unsigned number with

```
java.lang.Integer.parseUnsignedInt("ffffffff",16)  // Results in -1
```

or

```
java.lang.Long.parseUnsignedLong("ffffffffffffffff",16)  // Results in -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell it how long your number is one way or another. Without it, just saying "ffffffff" is ambiguous: as an `Int` it is -1, but as a long it is a large positive value:

```
 bigInt.toLong
 res48: Long = 4294967295

 bigInt.toInt
 res49: Int = -1
```

Comment: What if it is an extremely long number though, more than 32 bits of signed number?

Comment: There is no standard hex representation for those, AFAIK, but something like this `BigInt("-deadba0babbadc0ffee", 16)` will work.

Comment: Say for instance I wanted to represent `-2^64` with hex, which would be something like  `ff0000000000000000`. There isn't a way to do this with a standard library? I'm trying create a symmetric encoding from BigInt -> hex -> BigInt

Comment: `BigInt("-ff00000000000000", 16)`